# how to use create() method in laravel DB class

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a new row using the following SQL instead of eloquent

the code I am trying with :

```
$create_transections = DB::table('package_plan_fees')
        ->create([
            'paid_amount' => $post_data['total_amount'],
            'enroll_able' => $post_data['enrollable'],
            'user_id' => $post_data['user_id'],
            'package_id' => $post_data['package_id'],
            'plan_id' =>  $post_data['plan_id'],
            'status' =>  $post_data['status']
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `insert` instead of `create`.

You can check [Insert Statements](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#insert-statements) from Laravel documentation.

Your code needs to be like this:

```
$create_transections = DB::table('package_plan_fees')
        ->insert([
            'paid_amount' => $post_data['total_amount'],
            'enroll_able' => $post_data['enrollable'],
            'user_id' => $post_data['user_id'],
            'package_id' => $post_data['package_id'],
            'plan_id' =>  $post_data['plan_id'],
            'status' =>  $post_data['status']
        ]);
```

But because you [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757056/how-to-use-create-method-in-laravel-db-class/68757113?noredirect=1#comment121513722_68757113) you want to get inserted row's id, you can use `insertGetId` method which described in [Auto-Incrementing IDs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#auto-incrementing-ids) section of Laravel Documentation.

```
$inserted_rows_id = DB::table('package_plan_fees')
        ->insertGetId([
            'paid_amount' => $post_data['total_amount'],
            'enroll_able' => $post_data['enrollable'],
            'user_id' => $post_data['user_id'],
            'package_id' => $post_data['package_id'],
            'plan_id' =>  $post_data['plan_id'],
            'status' =>  $post_data['status']
        ]);
```

Comment: but I need to get new created row's ID by this code 'package_plan_fee_id' => $create_transections->id,

Comment: You can achieve it by using `insertGetId` method. Just replace `insert` on my answer with `insertGetId` and it will return inserted row's `id` value. To make it work the `package_plan_fees` table must have an auto-incrementing `id` field.

Comment: thanks for your help bro, I am sorry I have to accept the first one

Comment: Actually my answer is first one. My answers creation time is: "2021-08-12 12:01:11Z" and other's is "2021-08-12 12:01:40Z" My answer is 29 seconds early. You can check by hover your mouse over answer time. Because I updated my answer after you wanted to learn about `id` and it shows after that on listing. It is not a problem, happy to solve your problem.

Comment: Uğur Arıcı ok bro, I changed the mark, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There is no `create` method. You need to use `insert`. Relevant documentation page is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#insert-statements).

```php
DB::table('package_plan_fees')
    ->insert([
        'paid_amount' => $post_data['total_amount'],
        'enroll_able' => $post_data['enrollable'],
        'user_id' => $post_data['user_id'],
        'package_id' => $post_data['package_id'],
        'plan_id' =>  $post_data['plan_id'],
        'status' =>  $post_data['status']
   ]);
```

Comment: but I need to get new created row's ID

Comment: @azim Then you can use `insertGetId` It'll return the id

Answer (score 1):

```
create_transections = DB::table('package_plan_fees')
        ->insertGetId([
            'paid_amount' => $post_data['total_amount'],
            'enroll_able' => $post_data['enrollable'],
            'user_id' => $post_data['user_id'],
            'package_id' => $post_data['package_id'],
            'plan_id' =>  $post_data['plan_id'],
            'status' =>  $post_data['status']
        ]);
```

In order to insert & get inserted id back, you need to use insertGetId() method.

Comment: thanks for your help bro, I am sorry I have to accept the first one

Comment: @azim That's fine bro. You got the answer, that matters.